# What is window["uppload-vue"].default doing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, frontend

Can someone tell me what the following line does?

```
const UpploadVue = window["uppload-vue"].default
```

Used in [this example](https://github.com/elninotech/uppload/blob/master/wrappers/vue/example/index.html)

uppload-vue is a vue component.

Up til now I've always used an import statement to use an npm package within my .vue files, like below.

```
import vue from 'vue'
```

Is it something to do with the package being brought in the script tag in the head, rather than npm?  hence window?

Many thanks

Comment: When a package exports a name, it becomes a global variable. `window["variablename"]` allows you to access that global variable.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar  This sounds like a basic thing I should have known, but never come across before. Now I know :-)

Comment: You're probably more used to things like `import Foo` followed by using `new Foo`. That's a global variable `Foo`. But `uppload-vue` has a hyphen in it, so it can't be used as a variable name, you have to use the array syntax to access the property.